# zsh: Echoing every statement?

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, emacs

I have an odd problem with zsh when I switch between shells in a particular way:

#### Option 1 (works well):

I start a `zsh` shell. I switch to `tcsh` with `/bin/tcsh`, and I switch back to `zsh` with `/bin/zsh`

If I then run:

```
> ls
```

I get:

```
./  ../ file1 file1 file3
```

#### Option 2 (problematic):

I start a `zsh` shell. I switch to `tcsh` with:

`exec env -i HOME=$HOME TERM=$TERM DISPLAY=$DISPLAY /bin/tcsh`.

and I then switch back to `zsh` with `/bin/zsh`. If I then enter any commands, the `zsh` shell echoes the command and then the result. Using the same example as before:

```
> ls

2;ls --color=yes -aF1;./ ../ file1 file2 file3
```

In other words, zsh shows `2;COMMAND 1;` and then the output, which is of course very different from what I was getting with **Option 1**.

What's even more strange is that this only happens within `ansi-term` or `multi-term` terminals in Emacs, and not under `gnome-terminal`.

What else can I do to diagnose the problem? Any thoughts on what may be causing this?

## Update:

My `.cshrc` prompt is

```
set prompt = "> "
```

Comment: Escape code to update the title of your terminal

Comment: what is `$prompt` set to in tcsh? Do `tcsh -V` and `zsh -x` give a clue?

Comment: Thanks @UlrichDangel. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Thanks @StephaneChazelas. I updated the OP with prompt info. Is there anything in particular that you recommend I pay attention to in the trace?

Comment: @user815423426 something tries to update the title of your terminal to show the command you are running. as probably neither ansi-term nor multi-term terminal supports this they just show the escape codes instead of updating the title